# brew update only gives an older version of openssl

Tags: openssl, homebrew

I have openssl 1.0.2o installed, but I need a newer version.  Trying to use brew to do the update, but didn't work.  brew update still gives an older version of openssl, 1.0.2o, but not the standard version, which is 1.0.2j now in my understanding.

```
brew update
brew upgrade openssl

Error: openssl 1.0.2o already installed
```

I am expecting to download 1.0.2j at least of openssl.  Need help to do this.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL 1.0.2o **is** the latest version. It was released [one week ago](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/releases/tag/OpenSSL_1_0_2o). 1.0.2j is an old release that dates back to [September 2016](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/releases/tag/OpenSSL_1_0_2j).

---

In general, if `brew install <formula>` doesn’t install the latest version, you can check [Homebrew’s pull-requests](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Apr+openssl+is%3Aopen) to see if someone submitted an update. If you can’t find it, you can [submit it](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) yourself. Homebrew is run by volunteers who can’t always check all formulae for updates.

You can check the pull request that updated OpenSSL in Homebrew from 1.0.2n to 1.0.2o [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/25838/files).